# Fuel SDK - PHP (SOAP), Creating a folder results in "an unknown error"

Tags: soap-api, fuel-sdk, php, marketing-cloud, fuel

I am using the php Fuel SDK to create new folders and populate them with images.

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
function createFolder() {
  $client = getAuth();

  // Create Folder
  $postFolder = new ET_Folder();
  $postFolder->authStub = $client;
  // Folder setup
  $postFolder->props = array(
    "CustomerKey" => "image_storage",
    "Name" => "Image Storage",
    "Description" => "Image Storage",
    "ContentType"=> "Media",
    "ParentFolder" => array(
      "ID" => 0
    ),
    "AllowChildren" => "true",
    "IsEditable" => "true"
  );

  //post
  $postResult = $postFolder->post();
  return $postResult->results;
}
```

The issue i'm having is that every time this function is triggered i get an error message (*$ET_post->0['StatusMessage']*): **An unknown error occured while processing. Error ID:.......**.

[image]

does anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

My situation is somewhat different (I am using the SOAP API), but adding a comment as it might help others.  I had gotten the same cryptic error message when trying to create a datafolder without providing a value for the "description" property.  So make sure any datafolders you create have a description field (although I see in your case that you provided it.)

For Java (Apache CXF) based code, here is a sample:

```
    try {
        //Create PartnerAPI stub.
        PartnerAPI service = new PartnerAPI();
        Soap stub = service.getSoap();

        // Apache CXF-specific: if desired to see SOAP messages in console while running
        // Note logging credentials will be readable in the SOAP request if done
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(stub);
        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

        // used to specify BU for folder
        ClientID clientID = new ClientID();
        clientID.setID(xxxxxx); // MID value of the BU where you are adding the folder

        DataFolder parentFolder = new DataFolder();
        parentFolder.setID(xxxxxx);  // category ID of "My Emails" folder or other parent folder desired

        DataFolder df = new DataFolder();
        df.setClient(clientID);
        df.setParentFolder(parentFolder);
        df.setName("GlenFolder2");
        df.setDescription("GlenFolder desc");
        df.setContentType("Email");
        df.setIsEditable(true);
        df.setAllowChildren(true);

        CreateRequest cr = new CreateRequest();
        cr.getObjects().add(df);
        cr.setOptions(new CreateOptions());

        CreateResponse response = stub.create(cr);
        for (CreateResult result : response.getResults()) {
            System.out.println("Result = " + result.getStatusCode() + " " + result.getStatusMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Overall status = " + response.getOverallStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Possible DataFolder contentType values are defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm).